# Simple batch file if() failure

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

I am working on a short batch file program that accepts input and does some simple math. It seems to work correctly for everything except the first echo. Here is the code:

```
set /p usercommand= "Input:"
if "%usercommand%" equ "done" (

set /p usertimeouthours= "Input Hours: "
echo (%usertimeouthours%)

set /p usertimeoutminutes= "Input Minutes: "
echo (%usertimeoutminutes%)

set /p usertimeoutseconds= "Input Seconds: "
echo (%usertimeoutseconds%)

set /a answer= %usertimeouthours%*3600+%usertimeoutminutes%*60+%usertimeoutseconds%
echo %answer%

goto end
) else (
echo finished
goto user
)
:end
```

why does the first echo only output

> (

my guess is something is wrong with my if statement, does anyone know how I should change it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1 - Normal vs Delayed expansion of variables**
Normal expansion using `%var%` occurs at parse time, and the entire IF statement is parsed all at once, including the contents within the parentheses. So something like `echo (%usertimeouthours%)` displays the value of USERTIMEOUTHOURS as it existed before the IF statement was executed (before SET /P set the value).

The fix is to enable delayed expansion at the top using `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` and use `!var!` instead of `%var%`. Delayed expansion occurs at execution time instead of parse time.

**Problem 2 - Unescaped special characters**
There are a number of characters that have special meaning and must be either escaped with `^` or quoted if you want the character to be treated as a string literal.

One of the special characters is `)`. It will terminate any code block opened with `(` unless it is escaped or quoted. You need to escape that character as `^)` when you use it in your ECHO statements because those statements are within a parenthesized block of code.

**Simplification of your SET /A statement**
You do not need to expand variables when used in a SET /A computation. You can simply use the variable name without enclosing in percents or exclamations. This convenience only works with SET /A.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /p usercommand= "Input:"
if "%usercommand%" equ "done" (

  set /p usertimeouthours= "Input Hours: "
  echo (!usertimeouthours!^)

  set /p usertimeoutminutes= "Input Minutes: "
  echo (!usertimeoutminutes!^)

  set /p usertimeoutseconds= "Input Seconds: "
  echo (!usertimeoutseconds!^)

  set /a answer= usertimeouthours*3600+usertimeoutminutes*60+usertimeoutseconds
  echo !answer!

  goto end
) else (
  echo finished
  goto user
)
:end
```

Comment: First of all fantastic Answer. Secondly, I understand when execution happens, but when does parsing happen? In other words, can you give me a short explanation of how excatly Batch files are run? You can respond in a comment or I can ask it as another question if you want rep for it ;)

Comment: @John - You asked for it :-)  Have a look at [jeb's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/1012053) to the question "How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?"

Comment: That link was exactly what I needed. Thanks so much. Also on a completely unrelated note. I just looked at your profile and you give really great answers.. but you almost never ask questions why is that?